# How to Increase Maximum Upload File Size in WordPress in LOCALHOST

Tags: wordpress

I have a huge file, 7GB to upload on my localhost. It is a copy of my live website that includes almost everything - themes, contents and media files.

Is there any way to migrate this? I tried to use All-in-One WP Migration plugin but the upload limit is only 300MB.

Another way to increase is by editing the .htaccess, **but I cannot find it in the localhost.**

**Update .htaccess file**
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

Comment: Upload to your local machine from where exactly?

Comment: You need to update your php.ini file. In that configuration file you will find upload size variables. Some variables worth editing:

```upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300```. Also you need to the same in wordpress ```@ini_set('xxx', 'xxx')```

Comment: You need to change in /php/php.ini ! and just add in wp-config.php `@ini_set('upload_max_size' , '256M' );`

Comment: @esqew as i have mentioned 7GB is the copy (backup) of the live site. I am trying to setup the site on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

*Just do the following steps, it may increase your size.*

> **1. Editing the .htaccess File**

- Increase additional PHP limits by adding these lines into the .htaccess file :

  ```
  php_value post_max_size 256M
  php_value memory_limit 512M
  php_value max_input_time 180
  php_value max_execution_time 180
  ```

> **2. Editing the wp-config.php File**

- the `wp-config.php` file located in your root directory. edit the wp_config. php file. Add the following line.

  ```
  @ini_set('upload_max_size' , '256M' );
  ```

> **3. Updating php.ini**

- Navigate to your `php.ini` file and edit it. If you can’t find it, ask assistance from your hosting providers.
  Locate the `upload_max_filesize` and increase it by changing its number. You can also boost a few other limitations, as shown below:

  ```
  upload_max_filesize = 256M 
  post_max_size = 256M 
  memory_limit = 512M 
  max_execution_time = 180
  ```

Save the file, and that’s it, the error should no longer occur.

Comment: May I know what is the maximum upload size? My file is 7GB.

Comment: @ron.px you can change it to `7G`, but if you can divide your file and then upload that it better for your project if possible t.